# Realtime monitoring tools for Oracle 11g

Tags: user-interface, monitoring, real-time, oracle11g

I'm working on an app that use oracle 11g as db. I want to make some changes in the app and measure the performance before and after the changes.

I'm searching a graphical tool that presents the information in realtime while the app are making querys to oracle.

Something like the information showed in the section 10.4.3 here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/instance_tune.htm#CACGAHAD

Suggestions?

Must run on a machine with windows xp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked to a report that provides information about the performance of a single SQL statement.  That doesn't seem to fit with the rest of your question.  If you are making changes to the application and monitoring the effect in the database, that would normally imply that you are changing the SQL statement in some way.  You might be reducing the number of times that a SQL statement is called, in which case you wouldn't want nearly that level of detail about the performance of the SQL statement-- you'd just want to count the number of times it was executed and potentially a handful of statistics about the SQL statement.

Assuming that what you are really interested in is the performance of the database as a whole and assuming that you have the enterprise edition of the database with the Performance and Tuning Pack (which would be required to produce the report you linked to), you probably want to use the Enterprise Manager Database Control which is a web-based application for managing the Oracle database.  Within Enterprise Manager, there are a number of real-time performance graphs.  You can also invoke the [Automatic Database Diagnostic Monitor (ADDM)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28275/tdppt_manual.htm#CHDHGBIC) within Enterprise Manager to monitor performance before and after the changes are made.

Alternately, you could generate an [Automatic Workload Repository (AWR)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/autostat.htm#PFGRF94203) or [Statspack](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/statspac.htm#34837) report before and after the changes.  An AWR report would require the same Performance and Tuning Pack license that I was discussing in the prior paragraph.  A Statspack report would have much of the same information that would be on the AWR report though it is a little older and does require a bit of effort to set up.